# How best to do bitbucket pipeline automatic versioning?

Tags: git, shell, deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, semantic-versioning

These days at work, I was asked if it was possible to do automated pipeline versioning.

After researching about I found some examples using date versioning, like:`2021.21.09.153507`

My sh that performs the versioning:

```
git pull --rebase origin dev
npm install -g json

year=$(date +'%Y')
month=$(date +'%m')
day=$(date +'%d')
hours=$(date +'%H')$(date +'%M')$(date +'%S')

newVersion="$year.$month.$day.$hours"
json -I -f package.json -e "this.version=\"$newVersion\""

git add package.json
git commit -m "[skip ci]"
git push origin dev
```

Everything worked out with this solution, but we always use versioning manual with the semantic like this: `1.0.0`

Is it possible to identify which branch is being merged and thus create conditions to increase the version depending on some tag in the commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/).

Bitbucket Pipelines provide a set of default variables that are available for builds, and can be used in scripts. Values include `BITBUCKET_BRANCH` (source branch), `BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH` (pull request destination branch),
`BITBUCKET_TAG`, `BITBUCKET_COMMIT` and many others.

Moreover, I can tell from my own experience that the list provided by that link is not exhaustive - there are more potentially interesting variables available for your build which are undocumented for some reason. Running `printenv` somewhere in your pipeline will reveal them in their entirety.